# $\sin^3x+\sin^32x+\sin^33x=(\sin x+\sin 2x+\sin 3x)^3$

Tags: trigonometry

$\sin^3x+\sin^32x+\sin^33x=(\sin x+\sin 2x+\sin 3x)^3$. We have to find the least positive angle in degrees satisfying the equation above. I wrote sin2x as 2sinxcosx and sin3x as 3sinx-4sin$^3$x. But that method was too long. The answer is 72 in degrees

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3 \implies (a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=0$.